# Combine two tables without ruin the content of original columns

Tags: sql, database, union

I have a Table_A and Table_B as below, how can I create a UNION to generate a result set likes Table_C, so that the original content of the columns in Table_A and Table_B are kept.

Table_A:

```
ID    High_Level_Text
-------------------------
01    High Level Text One
02    High Level Text Two
03    High Level Text Thr
```

Table_B:

```
ID    Key    Low_Level_Text
----------------------------------
01    001    Low Level Text 01/001
01    002    Low Level Text 01/002
01    003    Low Level Text 01/003
02    001    Low Level Text 02/001
03    002    Low Level Text 03/002
```

Table_C:

```
ID    Key    High_Level_Text      Low_Level_Text
-------------------------------------------------------
01           High Level Text One
01    001                         Low Level Text 01/001
01    002                         Low Level Text 01/002
01    003                         Low Level Text 01/003
02           High Level Text Two
02    001                         Low Level Text 02/001
03           High Level Text Thr
03    002                         Low Level Text 03/002
```

In Table_C, records of the High_Level_Text column are left empty for those records where there's no original data from Table_A, same with Low_Level_Text and Key column for Table_B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select a.id as "ID",
  null as "KEY",
  a.High_level_text as "High_level_text",
  null as "Low_Level_Text"
from table_a a
union
select b.id,
  b.key,
  null,
  b.Low_Level_Text
from table_b b
order by 1,  2
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3683c6/9)</kbd>

This sets the columns you want in your result in the first `select` (the column names are defined in the first select of an `UNION`). Then you `order by` at the end, which will affect the complete resultset.

Comment: Couldn't he use group_id http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/06/sql-server-grouping-id-example.html?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be of use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, NULL as Key, High_Level_Text, NULL as Low_Level_Text
FROM Table_A
UNION
SELECT ID, Key, NULL as High_Level_Text, Low_Level_Text
FROM Table_B
ORDER BY ID
```

Check this [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4fc7b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT id, `key` , `low_level_text` , NULL AS `high_level_text`
FROM table_b
UNION ALL
SELECT id, NULL AS `key` , NULL AS `low_level_text` , `high_level_text`
FROM table_a
ORDER BY id ASC
```